# Geolocation package with laravel: Midnite81\Geolocation\GeoLocationServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.5

I want to use the following package for geolocation with laravel.
https://github.com/midnite81/geolocation

I have done everything they wrote in their documentation but find an error

> Midnite81\Geolocation\GeoLocationServiceProvider' not found

i am unable to solve this problem. Can't understand what's wrong. What i did, at first, write `"midnite81/geolocation": "1.*"` in the composer.json file.

```
 "require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "midnite81/geolocation": "1.*"
},
```

After that run `composer update`. Then  run `composer dump-autoload -o`. Then in the `config/app.php` file, put the following part in `providers` and `aliases` array.

```
'providers' => [

  Midnite81\Geolocation\GeoLocationServiceProvider::class

];

'aliases' => [

  'GeoLocation' => Midnite81\GeoLocation\Facades\GeoLocation::class,

];
```

then run the following command.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Midnite81\GeoLocation\GeoLocationServiceProvider"
```

Then got the error, `Midnite81\Geolocation\GeoLocationServiceProvider' not found`

Can't figure out what's wrong in it.

Comment: My error. Made a mistake in the read me. I've updated the docs with Marcin's pull request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I verified and confirm the problem.

The problem is:

```
Midnite81\Geolocation\GeoLocationServiceProvider::class
```

You should change this into

```
Midnite81\GeoLocation\GeoLocationServiceProvider::class
```

Notice the difference `Geolocation` vs `GeoLocation`. It seems there is error in readme for this package on Github

I've already sent Pull request https://github.com/midnite81/geolocation/pull/2 to fix readme for this package

Comment: Great Spot! Thanks Marcin :) I've merged that into the package.